# On Search Result: Group Products by Category

Tags: magento-1, product-list, catalogsearch

I need the search result page to list products grouped by category name.

Example: When searching for `nike` the result should be viewed like this:

```
Category "Shoes":
  - some nike shoe
  - another nike shoe

Category "Shirts":
  - some nike shirt
  - another nike shirt
  - ..

Category ...
  - ...
```

So far I tried to modify my `list.phtml` to simply cycle through all active store categories and check each found product (from getLoadedProductCollection()) if its assigned to that category. It's working, but slow as hell. So I think there must be some more Magento-like way to do this, but I don't know where to start. Anyone got some tip for me? Thanks

Comment: This is a really nifty thought/feature. I have to wonder, though, is this necessary if you enable layered navigation on the search page? Can't users just drill down to specific categories?

Comment: Good point! Haven't thought about that. Added with some ajax this will do the trick.

Comment: So is this solved?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Display Products Grouped By Subcategories](http://www.customy.com/display-products-grouped-by-subcategories.html) extension on category list pages before with success.

Another solution before we found this extension was to get the collection in the block and use a special attribute to order the collection. The code was as follows (only works under PHP 5.3)

```
class Class_Name
{
    [...]
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        [...]

        $collection = $this->_productCollection;

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('category_sort_value');


        // Do some fancy sorting
        $collectionReflection = new ReflectionObject($collection);
        $itemsPropertyReflection = $collectionReflection->getProperty('_items');
        $itemsPropertyReflection->setAccessible(true); // Make it accessible

        $collectionItems = $itemsPropertyReflection->getValue($collection);

        usort($collectionItems, array("Class_Name", "cmp"));

        $itemsPropertyReflection->setValue($collectionReflection, $collectionItems);

        $itemsPropertyReflection->setAccessible(false); // Return restriction back
        // End them fancyness

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    public function cmp($a, $b) 
    {
        $a_sort = (int)$a->getData('category_sort_value');
        $b_sort = (int)$b->getData('category_sort_value');

        if ($a_sort == $b_sort) return 0;
        return ($a_sort < $b_sort) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

You can use this class example to extend the Block class for the product list in search and sort the results like that. I hope this will help you in the right direction.

Comment: any idea how to get this snippet to work with php 5.5?

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz no clue to be honest