# Search results give unrelated category results - why?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

If I type in "pink" in the search box, I get 4 of my products that are pink.

Is there a way to search and have the results post only categories related to the search results?

Because when you click on "category A" (from the results page) that has a product count of 15 next to it, you actually get a "no results" page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a related thread covering what you're looking for:

- [On Search Result: Group Products by Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/on-search-result-group-products-by-category)

You'll also want to checkout the alternatives, out-of-box Magento uses MySQL's search capabilities which is severely limited compared to something like Google.

- [Providing Site Wide Search for Community Edition](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/providing-site-wide-search-for-community-edition)

Comment: - Let me rephrase...Literally my search results page provides the matching products but it also has a list of all of my categories on the left. 95% are links that go to "no results" pages as we only have like 2 categories with pink products in them.

Comment: Look further into the faceted/layered navigation. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work